# Angular2 + MaterializeCss Botones no recuperan color después de hacer click

Tags: angularjs-2.0, materialize, system.js

Estoy usando Angular2 con la libreria MaterializeCss (https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize)

Al hacer click en los botones, estos no recuperan el color, quedando finalmente blancos si se sigue haciendo clicks.

No se me ocurre la razón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Ignacio. Por favor agrega tu código como texto, no como imagen. De esa forma si alguien quiere responderte, puede copiar y pegar el código. Además pensemos en personas que estén leyendo en celulares con pantallas chicas o que tengan problemas de vista. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: Ok! gracias por responder, lo tendré presente!

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver el problema. Estoy trabajando con SystemJs. Estaba cometiendo el error de importar Materialize.js desde mi Index.html, siendo que systemJs ya lo importaba.

Espero a alguien le sirva esto.